# there must be only one primary contact on account by utilising isprimary checkbox

Tags: apex, map, list, contact, after-trigger

**stuck in here What if someone uses dataloader and make 2 contacts for same account as primary, then my code is not working**

```
public class Contactispr {
    public static void Conta(List<Contact> newContacts) {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> newtrueIds = new Set<Id>();
        system.debug(newContacts);
        for (Contact contact : newContacts) {
            if (contact.AccountId != null && contact.isprimary__c == true) {
                accountIds.add(contact.AccountId);
                newtrueIds.add(contact.Id);
                system.debug(accountIds);
            }
        }
        
        if (!accountIds.isEmpty()) {
            
            List<Contact> existingPrimaryContacts = [
                SELECT Id, isprimary__c, AccountId 
                FROM Contact 
                WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds AND isprimary__c = true AND Id NOT IN :newtrueIds 
            ];
            system.debug(existingPrimaryContacts);
            
            if (!existingPrimaryContacts.isEmpty()) {
                for(Contact existingContact : existingPrimaryContacts){
                    existingContact.isprimary__c = false;
                }
                update existingPrimaryContacts;
                system.debug(existingPrimaryContacts);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void firstCon(List<Contact> neContacts){
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        system.debug(neContacts);
        for(Contact Con : neContacts){
            if(Con.AccountId != null && Con.isprimary__c == false){
                accountIds.add(Con.AccountId);
            }
            
            if (!accountIds.isEmpty()) {
                
                List<Contact> existingPrimaryContacts = [
                    SELECT Id, AccountId 
                    FROM Contact 
                    WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds AND isprimary__c = false
                ];
                if(existingPrimaryContacts.isEmpty()){
                    Con.isprimary__c=True;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail and describe the troubleshooting you have done.  What actually happens when two contacts are marked as Primary?  Do you get a error message?  Please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

Following use case can be achieved in Before Insert Trigger Context. Here I have maintained a set of Account Id, If there are multiple AccountId in same batch (Uploading from Data Loader) we can either set the isPrimary as False or we can throw a Validation Error.

To throw validation error I have created a field Primary_Contact_Validation__c with default value as false and created a validation rule with the following field.

```
public class Contactispr {

public static void Conta(List<Contact> newContacts){
    Set<string> setofAccountId = new Set<string>();
    for(Contact contactObj : newContacts){
        if(contactObj.AccountId != null && contactObj.isprimary__c == true){
            if(!setofAccountId.contains(contactObj.AccountId)){    //Check the duplicacy
                setofAccountId.add(contactObj.AccountId);
            }else{
                contactObj.isprimary__c = false; //Set IsPrimary as False in case of duplicates
                contactObj.Primary_Contact_Validation__c = true; //Throw a Validation Error
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Update existing contacts to False
    List<Contact> existingConListToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    for(Contact conObj : [SELECT Id,Name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :setofAccountId and isprimary__c = true]){
        conObj.isprimary__c = false;
        existingConListToUpdate.add(conObj);
    }
    
    if(existingConListToUpdate.size() > 0 && existingConListToUpdate != null){
        Database.update(existingConListToUpdate);
    }
    //Update existing contacts to False
}

}
```

I Hope It helps You !!!

[image]